# Static files of django, nginx and gunicorn app using docker?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am not able to get the static files to come up. I've tried various settings and directory configurations and so on, but they just turn up as 404s.

The folder structure of application as below

```
.
├── config
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── local.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── aggre
│   ├── aggre
│   └── manage.py
|   └── static
├── requirements.txt
```

Settings.py look like

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR),'static']
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), 'static')
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/django/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/django/src
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /tmp/
COPY . /opt/services/django/src
RUN python aggre/manage.py collectstatic --no-input  # <-- here
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
EXPOSE 8000
ADD . /opt/services/django/src
CMD ["gunicorn", "--chdir", "aggre", "--bind", ":8000", "aggre.wsgi:application"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  djangoapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/django/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/django/static/
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/opt/services/django/static/ 
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

local.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ***.***.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://djangoapp:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /opt/services/django/static;
    }
}
```

I am building and running using
**

> docker-compose up --built

The application is started successfully but static files are not loaded.
I am getting

> "/opt/services/django/src/static/js/bootstrap.js" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory)
>   **

I am not getting where it is failing to load the static files.

Comment: It'll help if you understand how the image is built. When you run docker build, all of the files in your local dir (where the Dockerfile is) are sent to the host with the docker daemon. That's called the "context". Then the docker daemon creates a temp container and runs the instructions in your Dockerfile one by one in that container. At the end, the temp container is deleted and you're left with an image. So, your Dockefile should COPY files from the context into the temp container, then RUN setup instructions. CMD is only executed when a container is created from your new image.

Comment: I suggest you read this https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Thank you.I am not getting where it is failing to load the static files.

Comment: What is `BASE_DIR` set to in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @WillKeeling
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))